# What is Environment variable and how should I set it for ionic?

Tags: 14.04, android, environment-variables, android-sdk

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to create an ionic project. When I try to build my project with:

```
ionic build android
```

It says

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.

Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

I googled about it and found that I need to set the environment variable that refers the sdk path. Some say to set it in the `.profile` file and some say to set it in `.zshrc` file (I am using `zsh` as my shell). But neither works for me.

Can anyone tell me what an environment variable is and how I would set it? I have only basic knowledge in Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: How did you "set" the variable exactly?

Comment: Now there is nothing set. i deleted everything to start fresh.

Comment: can you explain how should i set it?

Comment: I meant how did you try to set it when it didn't work exaclty? `ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk` or `export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk`?

Comment: export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/sdk this one

Comment: And where are you running `ionic build android` from? Are you sure the path is correct? `export ANDROID_HOME='/path/to/sdk'` in `~/.zshrc` should have worked for all interactive shells (in the console, in a terminal etc).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36731/discussion-between-hari-krishnan-and-kos).

Comment: look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32557569/3734222)